# How to remove a row from DataGridView if data within Total column is Zero

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

Hello Everyone Good Afternoon

I have a program that imports excel into datagridview but when after I import it the look is like this.

[Link of the Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gIZPW.png)

as what you see in the image above I have a Column `Total` which composed of NULL(Empty String),0 and a certain data.

I wonder how can I delete the whole row if the column `Total` has a Data of `NULL` or `0`.

Im using this code and it applies in Datagridview

```
Private Sub step_3_delete_Zero()
    Dim SkipRemove As Boolean
    Dim Rowindex As Integer

    For Rowindex = DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
        SkipRemove = False

        For Each Cell As DataGridViewCell In DataGridView1.Rows(Rowindex).Cells
            If Not Cell.Value.ToString = "0" Then
                SkipRemove = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next

        If Not SkipRemove = False Then
            DataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(Rowindex)
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

I hope someone helps me, TY in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your for each loop where have you said to look in the total cell?

Are you looking in every cell in that row?

Also isn't `If SkipRemove = True Then` easier to read than `If Not SkipRemove = False Then`?

I think it's not working because you are looping through and checking each cell rather than looping through by row and then checking the specific cell on each row.

Would something along the lines of this be more easier?

```
For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
    If row.Cells.Item("Total").Value = "0" Then
             DataGridView1.Rows.Remove(row)
    End If
Next
```